# How to make a tile size larger in Windows 8.1 Start Menu if there is no option for resizing it to 'large'?

Tags: windows

I wanted to customize my start menu such that some of my tiles are large. But I have noticed that windows allows only small and medium sizes for certain tiles.
I wanted to make a tile large in size, so is there any way to tweak windows to allow me to choose my tile size of my own choice??
Please help?

Answer (score 0):

If the application is not UWP and is a classic desktop application, only the small and medium options are available. Only the medium tile option is required for any app, and windows takes the app icon for that tile size. For the 'small' size it just scales the medium size image.

But when it comes to UWP apps, it is the developer's choice on which sizes to support for their apps according to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/secondary-tiles-pinning)

> To enable wide and large tile sizes, you need to provide the Wide310x150Logo and Square310x310Logo. Also, if possible, you should provide the Square71x71Logo for the small tile size (otherwise we will downsize your required Square150x150Logo for the small tile).

So there isn't much that you can change from your side apart from the available options it seems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!